# Align a sub divs text with parent div

Tags: css, html, text, alignment

I am currently working on a website, very simple, but my first one. I am creating the header right now and I can't get my "Big Header"'s text to align with my "Header"'s text.

See, http://www.dummycode.com, for my website.

I want `Dummy Code` to align with `home about projects blog donate` but it is below it.

My style CSS is at http://dummycode.com/style.css

The two "methods" in my style sheet are below...

```
#header { 
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    width:795px;
    height:100px; 
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin-left:-397.5px;

    text-align:right;
    background:white;

    padding-top:35px;
    padding-bottom:35px;
    padding-right:10px;

    font-size:30px;
    word-spacing:12px;
    text-transform:lowercase;

    position:fixed;
}
#bigheader {
    padding-left:10px;
    font-size:50px;
    word-spacing:0px;
    text-align:left;
    text-transform:none;
    position:fixed;
}
```

And my HTML is here...

```
<div id="header">
<div id="bigheader">
<h>Dummy Code</h>
</div>
    <a class="current" href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="./about">About</a>
    <a href="./projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="./blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="./donate">Donate</a>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: set the `line-height` equal for the header and the links, display:inline-block. Also, that should be an <h1> or <h2>, not just <h>

Comment: Your HTML is semantically very wrong. You should learn the correct way to markup a site, and use floats instead of `position:fixed`, and an `unordered list` for the navigation. You should always add a reset css in to work from a consistent base-line across all browsers - because of the different default styles that browsers add to the page.

Comment: Are you using software to write this?  The CSS seems a little extraneous for what you need to do.

Comment: @hungerstar Nope, just a smaller part of my website. 100% written with Notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have used fixed position you could just give `#bigheader` and `top` value.

```
#bigheader {
    // current css goes here
    top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree wit @Nick R.  You should be using semantic code and floats along with un-ordered lists for this.  Here is a more proper approach.

**CSS**

```css
#primary-nav-container h1,
#primary-nav,
#primary-nav li {
     float: left;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
#primary-nav-container {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 795px;
}
#primary-nav-container h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#primary-nav {
     float: right;
}
#primary-nav li {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 6px;
}
#primary-nav a {
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header id="primary-nav-container">
     <h1>Dummy Code</h1>
     <ul id="primary-nav">
          <li>
               <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
               <a href="./about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
               <a href="./projects">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li>
               <a href="./blog">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li>
               <a href="./donate">Donate</a>
          </li>
     </ul>
</header>
```

You could even toss a `<nav>` tag in there to be a little more semantic.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `position: fixed` to position the "Dummy Code" header, just use `display: inline-block`.  Then you can use `vertical-align: middle` on all of the elements of the header to align them as desired

Comment: Then I cannot do `text-align:left;`

Comment: @HenryHarris that doesn't appear to make a difference to me

Comment: I want it looking like this **BIG TEXT** --------   _Little Text_

Comment: Everything is aligned to the left by default.